# OpenGL object manipulating from shader

Tags: c++, opengl

This may seem like a basic question, but how can you work with/manipulate objects created with the help of shaders in OpenGL?

I am always in the need of the coordinates of different objects, to use in my host program, to create/manipulate different objects, based on those coordinates and then send them back to the vertex/fragment/geometry shader.

I have my initial vertex coordinates, that I have defined in my main program, but once they reach the geometry shader, the position is computed via:

```
gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * vec4(square_point,1);
EmitVertex();
```

And now, for example, I need to select and move them with the mouse, on the screen. But there is no easy way that I can think of getting the exact coordinates. 
I've tried to do the position math in my main program, but I do not seem to get the same coordinates as the ones computed by the geometry shader. And calculating all on the CPU, is not really that optimal for the number of object that I have.

I've thought of doing some GPU->CPU data retrieve, via buffers, but there are so many object and so many coordinates, that it's relentless.

I imagine that there is another way to approach this, just that I may not have the proper knowledge of how OpenGL works.

Comment: Are you correctly dealing with the `w` coordinate after transformation? That's a step (dividing all 4 vector components by it) that happens after the Geometry Shader runs. If you're capturing the emitted vertices and comparing those, they won't have had this step performed yet.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - I do not think so. I am applying the exact formula that I've put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use so called shader storage buffer objects`SSBO`. You create them in your shader with the `buffer` qualifier. Then you do the necessary computation and download your data via `glMapBufferRange` and `memcpy` .